# SQL Server 2008 - query to order by a column with odd and even numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm in trouble and I need a quick answer, please.

I have a table in which I have a column containing only odd and even numbers.

I want to select first only the rows with the `orderByColumn` containing odd numbers, then add the result to the "even query"

My table looks like this

```
col1   col2   orderByColumn  col4
...................................
 c       c         44          c
 c       c         45          c
 c       c         46          c
...................................
...................................
```

I guess I should make an union, which I think would look like this:

```
select * from myTable 
where [orderByColumn] % 2 = 0  --order by [orderByColumn]-->error

UNION

select * from myTable 
where [orderByColumn] % 2 > 0  order by [orderByColumn]
```

The query does union the 2 selects, but obviously, they are merged and order by `orderByColumn`  which I don't want to.

I want the results to look like this:

```
c c 44 c
c c 46 c
c c 48 c
........
c c 45 c
c c 47 c
c c 49 c
........
```

Any ideas ? Thank you:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for the even numbers first:

```
select *
from myTable
order by [orderByColumn]%2, orderbycolumn
```

Use `desc` if you want the odd numbers first.

Comment: +1 you would still need to add `,orderByColumn` to the `order by` to guaranteed order of the odd/even values.

Comment: If you want the numbers to be in order within the respective odd/even groups, you'll want to order by `orderByColumn` a second time

Answer (score 1):

You could also introduce a column with your sort value, like

```
    select *, 
    case when [orderByColumn]%2=0 then 0 else 1 end as isOdd
    from myTable 
    order by 
    isodd , orderbyColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
   OrderByColumn 
from 
   table 
where 
  mod(OrderByColumn,2) = 0 

union all 

select 
   OrderByColumn 
from 
   table 
where 
    mod(OrderByColumn,2) >0
```